# How to display plugin content in react using wordpress react API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I have a WordPress blog that is using a knowledge base plugin, now I would like to display content added to this KB to my react app using  [WordPress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/).

Now I am able to display normal posts and pages from my wordpress app as follows

```
componentDidMount() {
    const wordPressSiteURL = clientConfig.siteUrl;

    this.setState( { loading: true }, () => {
        axios.get( `${wordPressSiteURL}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/` )
            .then( res => {
                if ( 200 === res.status ) {
                    if ( res.data.length ) {
                        this.setState( { loading: false, posts: res.data } );
                        console.log('test', res.data)
                    } else {
                        this.setState( { loading: false, error: 'No Posts Found' } );
                    }
                }

            } )
            .catch( err => this.setState( { loading: false, error: err } ) );
    } )
}
```

Now How do I display my content from knowledge base (plugin) in my website to my react app?

Comment: You need to create your own routes (custom rest routes). You should be more specific about your plugin.

Comment: Please, specify the plugin name.
There is a lot of knowledge base plugins.
Maybe is it the plugin link https://wordpress.org/plugins/echo-knowledge-base/?

Comment: @AndriiKovalenko here is the plugin https://www.minerva-kb.com/topic/home-page-setup/

Answer (score 0):

This goes as standard WordPress wp-json format.
Let's Suppose you are trying to get content of certain taxonomy (namely 'topic'),

## This gives you the list of topics

`/wp-json/wp/v2/topic/`

## If you want to get meta-data of specific topic

`/wp-json/wp/v2/kb?topic=<topic_id>`

If you want to get full details of specific page
=> `/wp-json/wp/v2/kb?topic=<content_id>`

Just keep in mind that `post type` is `kb` and then check on `taxonomy`